# Loading sound with SDL2.0 causes exception in MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I have the following sound loading function:

```
bool Sound::load(const char* fileName)
{
    sound = Mix_LoadWAV(fileName);
    if (sound == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load sound at path: " << fileName << "SDL_mixer error: " << Mix_GetError();
        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

In Dev-C++, this works, fine. I wanted to use another IDE, so I started using Visual Studio 2017, and configured SDL2 for it. However, when I run this code, from the moment Mix_LoadWAV is called, Visual studio gives the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfPeY.jpg

I have searched alot on the internet, but I could not find anything useful that worked for me.

EDIT: as per request, I created a minimal example that still produces the same error.

```
#include "SDL2\SDL_mixer.h"
#include "SDL2\SDL.h"

#include <iostream>

#undef main

class SoundTest
{
private:
Mix_Chunk* sound = nullptr;
public:
bool load(const char* fileName)
{
    sound = Mix_LoadWAV(fileName);

    if (sound == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load sound at path: " << fileName << "SDL_mixer error: " << Mix_GetError();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
};

SDL_Window *window = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Sound bug? ", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 300, 300, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048);

    SoundTest sound;
    sound.load("audio/soundEffect.wav");
    while (true)
    {
        //Do fun stuff with the sound
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @genpfault I edited it, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Where's your `Mix_Init()` call?  Why are you `#undef`ing `main` and not calling [`SDL_SetMainReady()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady)?

Comment: #undef main is there because of the macro stuff SDL does to main. If SDL_SetMainReady() does that, I had never heard of that function. About Mix_Init(), Is that required? up to now, I have always used Mix_OpenAudio() without problems.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/W3EQBHWE) is working fine for me with fresh [SDL 2.0.7](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.7-VC.zip) and [SDL2_mixer 2.0.1](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.zip) x86 development binaries in VS2015.

Comment: I have reinstalled SDL, but your code does not work for me. I am using VS2017 though. Maybe that can be the problem? See [this](https://imgur.com/a/YhpNw) For a screenshot.

Comment: I have exactly the same SDL versions as you